# Convert string to decimal number in ruby

Tags: ruby, numbers, decimal

I need to work with decimals.
In my program, the user need to put a number with decimals to convert that number.

The problem is: If I try to convert the argument into a number I get a integer without decimals.

```
# ARGV[0] is: 44.33

size = ARGV[0]

puts size.to_i
# size is: 44
# :(
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You call `to_i`, you get integer.

Try calling `to_f`, you should get a float.

For more string conversion methods, [look here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_c).

Comment: There is `to_d` also, as stated in answer by Tau-fan https://stackoverflow.com/a/51494232/3090068

Answer (score 17):

If you want more accurate answer with the calculation to avoid bug like this https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/50fe886f68fc44056f00626c you can use conversion to decimal
example :

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'

size = ARGV[0]
size = size.to_d
```

this should make the printed number become decimal but if you want to make it as float again just put this to_f again

```
size=size.to_f

puts size
```

Answer (score 9):

You also can use the decimal class for it

```
a = '2.45'
Decimal(a) # => 2.45
```

UPDATE:

Use bigdecimal as @bigtex777 mentioned:

source: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `Decimal' for ... Another "feature / improvement" from the serial "formerly working-code" destruction-team, no doubt.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for either. You can `require 'bigdecimal'; BigDecimal.new('3.333')`

Comment: Yes, looks like Decimal() is a method from some specific ruby version that I couldn't remember. BigDecimal belongs to ruby stdlib. -> http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html It's better use it.

Comment: `BigDecimal.new('3.333')` does not work, should be `BigDecimal('3.333')`

Answer (score 1):

Capitalized conversion methods are a well-established Ruby idiom. [See this great post from Advi Grimm](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/05/07/a-ruby-conversion-idiom/)

```
Integer("641339524823408659")
=> 641339524823408659
```