# How to Get Rid of Double Quotation Marks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

> using gsub to remove double

```
a = "5.102"
a.gsub('\"', "") 

result = "5.102"
```

How may the quote marks from the return value be removed to obtain the following?

expected result = 5.102

Comment: `"5.102"` is a string printed as `5.102` without quotation marks - it really has no quotation marks. Instead, you are probably intending to parse to double.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to decimal number in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956766/convert-string-to-decimal-number-in-ruby)

Comment: Are you talking about what gets displayed in a console, or the actual value?

Comment: I am trying on the console.

Comment: Your question is unclear. There are no quotation marks in your string, so there is nothing to remove. What is *precisely* that you are trying to do? Can you give an *exact* specification what it is that you want to do, including corner cases, special cases, and exceptions to those rules? Can you give more examples of desired inputs and outputs? Can you maybe provide test cases that allow answerers to check whether their answers are correct?

Comment: Which command are you using to print to console? Using `p` you always get quotation marks in case of a string. You should use `puts`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use **.to_f** method on "5.102"

```
"5.102".to_f #=> 5.102
```

Comment: "5.102".to_f it is fine. But in case "5.100".to_f it removes last two zero. I always get them after the decimal three-point value.

Comment: Are you trying to store the variable or display it? If you are trying to store it in a variable , store it in a string format and while displaying use puts("%.3f" % [a]), else if you want to operate on it use.to_f before operating

Comment: The result is given in the string format. I am already trying this.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you need to differentiate between the internal representation of a number (as a string vs. as a number) and the external expression (formatting) of a number as a string. In general (except for rounding errors), `5.1` and `5.100` will be stored in memory identically when they are numbers, not strings. (This is also true mathematically speaking.)

You will probably want to store your value internally as a number, because then you will have access to number-y functionality like adding, rounding, etc. Converting the string (the thing you see with the double quotes) to a floating point number (a numeric value as opposed to a string value) can be done as described in the other answer, by using `to_f`:

```
2.5.1 :002 > "5.102".class
 => String
2.5.1 :003 > "5.102".to_f
 => 5.102
2.5.1 :004 > "5.102".to_f.class
 => Float
```

For zero padding output, we use sprintf style formatting in Ruby (as in C and many other languages):

```
2.5.1 :005 > "%.3f" % 5.102
 => "5.102"
2.5.1 :006 > "%.3f" % 5.1
 => "5.100"
```